# A faster way of copying values from a numpy array to another knowing that both arrays have different shapes

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix

what is the faster way of copying from an array into a matrix.
Example:

```
A = np.zeros((5, 3))
B = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

After copying values of B into A the resulting A should be:

```
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [ 0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0]]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: @OzanDeniz  thank you for the link but in my case I'm using two arrays with different shapes so no one of the three solutions could solve my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`np.put`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html):

```
In [74]: np.put(A, np.arange(len(B)), B)

In [75]: A
Out[75]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

or assign to [`A.flat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html):

```
A.flat[:len(B)] = B
```

or (as ali_m points out) *if `A` is C-contiguous*, you could use `A.ravel`:

```
assert A.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']
A.ravel()[:len(B)] = B
```

If `A` is not C-contiguous, then `A.ravel()` returns a copy. Modifying the copy does not modify `A`. Examples of non-C-contiguous arrays include slices with non-unit step size such as `A[::2]` and F-contiguous arrays such as `np.asarray(A, order='F')`.

---

You can use [Python's `timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to benchmark pieces of code. If you have [IPython](http://ipython.org/), a particularly convenient way to benchmark code snippets is to use its `%timeit` "magic" function:

```
In [83]: A = np.zeros((500, 300))

In [84]: B = np.tile(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),1000)

In [88]: %timeit A = np.zeros((500, 300)); A.flat[:len(B)] = B
10000 loops, best of 3: 158 µs per loop

In [89]: %timeit A = np.zeros((500, 300)); np.put(A, np.arange(len(B)), B)
1000 loops, best of 3: 238 µs per loop

In [18]: %timeit A = np.zeros((500, 300)); A.ravel()[:len(B)] = B
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.6 µs per loop
```

which suggests that `A.ravel()[:len(B)] = B` is the faster than `A.flat[:len(B)] = B` which is faster than `np.put(A, np.arange(len(B)), B)`.

Benchmarks can vary from machine to machine depending on many factors such as
hardware, OS, version of software, or how the software was compiled. One piece
of code could be faster than an alternative piece of code for small arrays but
slower for larger arrays. So when you really want to benchmark, be sure to test
the code on input, hardware and software closest to your actual use case, while
keeping in mind the futility of pre-optimization.

Comment: thank you very much it should be the solution but do you know which one is faster?

Comment: `A.ravel()[:len(B)] = B` is about 7x faster than `A.flat[:len(B)] = B` on my machine

Comment: @ali_m: The problem with `ravel` is that in some circumstances it returns a copy rather than a view. When it returns a copy, modification of the copy does not affect `A`. For example, let `C = np.zeros((500, 300))` then define `A = C[::2]`. Then `A.ravel()[:len(B)] = B` does not modify `A`.

Comment: Fair point, although since the OP was asking for a fast method, I still think `ravel` is worth mentioning for the common case where `A` is a C-contiguous array

Comment: @ali_m: Good point. I've edited the post to include `ravel`. Thanks very much.

Comment: Thank you guys! This solution solved my problem. In my case ravel and flat performed both nearly the same (55 seconds). But thank you @ali_m anyway!  It's good to learn something new :)